# What can be the impact of updating /etc/authorization file in mac os x 10.8.2

Tags: macos, instruments, ui-automation

We are using Bamboo for CI & UIAutomation testing in our project. For that we use scripts that builds the xcode project, creates .app file and then launch Instruments to run automation tests.
In our script for running automation scripts, we are getting following error:
"Failed to authorize rights (0x2) with status: -60007."
I searched for this error, and I got the solution saying updating "system.privilege.taskport" in "etc/authorization" file to allow root will solve the problem. Actually it did solved my problem. 
But, after that when the system was broken. I mean, I tried to restart it, and it didn't boot.
I haven't changed anything in the system. The only way recovering the machine was reinstalling it.

Now, with my new machine I am again getting the same error for the script. Can anyone help me to resolve it. without changing anything in system file. 
Also can anyone confirm the impact of changing "etc/authorization" file